# SQLAlchemy: AmbiguousForeignKeysError double reference to parent

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

I have the following simplified code for Groups that can have subgroups with roles:

```
from sqlalchemy import (
    CheckConstraint,
    Column,
    ForeignKey,
    PrimaryKeyConstraint,
    String,
    create_engine,
)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship

Base = declarative_base()


class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'
    name = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    group_roles = relationship('GroupRole', back_populates='group')


class GroupRole(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'group_roles'
    name = Column(String, ForeignKey(Group.name))
    group_name = Column(String, ForeignKey(Group.name))
    role = Column(String, nullable=False)
    __table_args__ = (
        CheckConstraint('name != group_name'),
        PrimaryKeyConstraint('name', 'group_name'),
    )
    group = relationship(Group,
                         foreign_keys=[name],
                         back_populates='group_roles')


engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)()
session.add(Group(name='test'))
```

When I run this, I get `sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Group.group_roles - there are multiple foreign key path
s linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.`

I have also tried adding the following below the `GroupRole` table in lieu of the corresponding line already defined in `Group`:

```
Group.group_roles = relationship('GroupRole', foreign_keys=[Column(String, ForeignKey(GroupRole.name))], back_populates='group')
```

But I get the same error, and it doesn't look like others have had to do this. What am I doing wrong? How can I get my `GroupRole` table to reference my `Group` table? I'm using SQLAlchemy 1.3 and python 3.7.

Comment: Why do you think you need this "double reference to parent" in the first place? In `GroupRole` you have both `name` and `group_name` explicitly defined as the same foreign key, and you also have `group` defined as a relationship. That actually looks more like a "triple reference to me". Perhaps try using just one.

Comment: So this is vastly simplified, I've also got user roles in the group in the actual code: at the end of the day I want each group to have a user_roles attribute that links to user roles and another that links to (sub) group_roles. I.e. A group is composed of other groups and users, each with their own roles

Comment: Maybe this is one of those rare cases where a less simplified example would make sense, I'd say just go with simple `backref` on the `GroupRole.group` relationship, but I can't help but feel that I am missing something from this picture with the double foreign key business paired with the check constraint. At any rate, my gut feeling is that this is more of an issue with the data model itself than anything else.

Comment: For an example, check my answer below. Still I am not sure about the foreign key on `Group.name` for `GroupRole.name`, maybe something a more detailed example could explain.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the code work with only `backref` on the `GroupRole.group` relationship, such as:

```
class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'groups'
    name = Column(String, primary_key=True)

class GroupRole(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'group_roles'
    name = Column(String, ForeignKey(Group.name))
    group_name = Column(String, ForeignKey(Group.name))
    role = Column(String, nullable=False)
    __table_args__ = (
        CheckConstraint('name != group_name'),
        PrimaryKeyConstraint('name', 'group_name'),
    )
    group = relationship(Group,
                         foreign_keys=[name],
                         backref='group_roles')
```

Not sure this is what is intended though, but working:

```
g = Group(name='test', group_roles=[
    GroupRole(group_name='testrole', name='test', role='testrole'),
    GroupRole(group_name='testrole2', name='test', role='testrole2')
])
session.add(g)
```